# Format of How Amazon Wishlist pages are showed

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

This is a conceptual question rather than a technical one and might seem silly but anyway here goes.

I'm trying to parse a public amazon wishlist given in this [link](http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/ref=cm_wl_search_26_nn?ie=UTF8&cid=A211MVVOQKJ8SL) using jsoup. I am able to do that currently.

As you can see in the above link, there are total 9 pages of in that wishlist in the format

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .. 9
```

If there were n pages in a public wishlist then will the format be

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7.. n
```

I need to know how all the pages in an Amazon Wishlist are represented so that I can code accordingly.

Links to various public Amazon Wishlists containing 2,5, 10, 20 pages are welcome to help understand how the pages are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options to know how many pages are in the list:

1. All the links to the other pages are at the same format: `http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_X/182-3573734-9320732?ie=UTF8&page=X` (the page number is `X` and it appears **twice** in the URL), so you can loop on X from 2 and on. You should get `200 OK` response for all the pages, until you hit a non existing one.
2. Download the first page and do:

   ```
   Elements e = document.select("#wishlistPagination > span:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
   String s = e.text();
   ```

   The string `s` contains now - `?Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 … 9 Next?` so find the number after the ellipsis or before "Next" and you're done.
   **EDIT**
   In a second thought - if the list contains 7 pages or less, there won't be "next" in the string, so the first method (fetching all the URLs and changing the page number X) is more robust.

Comment: So this logic will be true even if they are 100 pages in a Wishlist? i.e the format "Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 … 100 Next" ??